# TinyMCE table properties failing to update in IE11

Tags: tinymce, internet-explorer-11, tinymce-3

Using tinymce 3.7 We have a text editor where if one right clicks on a table to bring up table properties and changes the background color the changes are not reflected on the actual table after hitting update.

I tried searching to see if this was a known issue perhaps addressed in a later version of TinyMCE but could not find anything that appeared to discuss this particular issue. Is there a fix or at least documentation of this being a known tinyMCE issue that any of you know of?

Comment: There is no version of TinyMCE as 3.7. I think you meant 3.5.7?

Comment: quite probably. I know there was some confusion looking up the version number when I originally had this issue but I don't for the life of me know anymore which project it was.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues in TinyMCE with IE11. To solve those issues you'll have to upgrade to at least `3.5.10` version of TinyMCE. Everything works fine in `3.5.10`. I tested it on IE11. There's just one thing which will not work, that is `searchreplace`. For that you'll have to upgrade to `4.x` version of TinyMCE.